# Embed SDL's view into UIViewController

Tags: ios, 3d, sdl

Some of the SDL demo i've seen for iOS, all the rendering occurs inside of `SDL_Window` rather than `UIWindow`. However, as most iOS applications are modeled based on one single UIWindow. I would like to integrate iOS with SDL and embed SDL's window (or SDL's view) inside a UIViewController's view.  How is this accomplished?

I've post my questions [here](http://minko.io/forums/topic/embed-minko-3d-into-uiview/) and also see the following [comment](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=7352&highlight=uiview) by michelleC stating the following but I don't know how to code what michelleC mentioned. I don't have permission to post/reply on their forum.

> I pretty easy to get hold of the sdl window and add view controllers
>   to it, or get the encapsulated sdl view and add it to a view
>   controller.

What I've done so far was modifying SDL_uikitviewcontroller.m to reposition/resize SDL_Window's view:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = newFrame.size.height - 100;
    newFrame.size.width  = newFrame.size.width - 50;
    newFrame.origin.x = 25.0f;
    self.view.frame = newFrame;

    SDLUIKitDelegate *appDelegate = [SDLUIKitDelegate sharedAppDelegate];
    [appDelegate embedView:self.view];
}
```

I then pass that view to a function in SDL_uikitappdelegate.m where it will add the SDL_Window's view as subview of UIViewController. However, my encountered error.

```
- (void) embedView:(UIView*)vw {
    [vw removeFromSuperview];

    CGRect frame = vw.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 56.0f;
    vw.frame = frame;

    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:vw];
}

2014-10-11 12:53:51.723 Happy[16403:614428] -[SDLUIKitDelegate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbf11500d60
2014-10-11 12:53:51.725 Happy[16403:614428] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SDLUIKitDelegate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbf11500d60'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001115323f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111e04bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011153950d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011149160f ___forwarding___ + 495
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111491398 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Happy                               0x000000010f227eb1 -[SDLUIKitDelegate embedView:] + 289
    6   Happy                               0x000000010f26f968 -[SDL_uikitviewcontroller viewDidLayoutSubviews] + 1400
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010fcee1cc -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 572
    8   QuartzCore                          0x0000000111284f98 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    9   QuartzCore                          0x0000000111279bbe _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111279a2e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    11  QuartzCore                          0x00000001111e7ade _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    12  QuartzCore                          0x00000001111e8bea _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010fc8adb0 -[UIApplication _sendOrderedOutContextsAndInvalidate:] + 99
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010fc8ad2b orderOutContextObserverCallout + 34
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111467347 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001114672a0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011145c9e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    18  Happy                               0x000000010f223667 UIKit_PumpEvents + 71
    19  Happy                               0x000000010f1b0b10 SDL_PumpEvents + 48
    20  Happy                               0x000000010f1b0b88 SDL_WaitEventTimeout + 56
    21  Happy                               0x000000010f1b0b4a SDL_PollEvent + 26
    22  Happy                               0x000000010f16d883 SDL_main + 195
    23  Happy                               0x000000010f227d3e -[SDLUIKitDelegate postFinishLaunch] + 46
    24  Foundation                          0x000000010f81ea75 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 387
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011149a4e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011149a0a5 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011145d3dd __CFRunLoopRun + 1901
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011145ca06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001130209f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    30  UIKit                               0x000000010fc75550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    31  Happy                               0x000000010f227608 main + 328
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001121c6145 start + 1
    33  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was due to my code referencing bad variable. The following line in embedView: should be replaced instead:

[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:vw];

with

[myWindow.rootViewController.view addSubview:vw];

Comment: Hi Loc Pham, I also want to integrate storyBoard with my SDL game. But most of the article just 1 time SDL Launch, I am wondering is this workable to swift 3? If not, i need a bridge header instead.